# How can I find the area of a rectangle created by the spiral r=theta at a certain theta?

Tags: curves-and-surfaces

I would like to have a function that gives the area of a rectangle at a certain theta of the spiral r=theta. The height of the rectangle is the y value of the point on the spiral and the base of the rectangle is the x value of the point on the spiral. I know the area would then just be xy (positive if its above the x axis and negative if below the x axis) for each point (x,y) on the curve. I know that r=theta can be written in cartesian coordinates as tan(sqrt(x^2+y^2)) = y/x, but I don't know if I can solve this equation for x or y.

For example, given F(5 * sqrt(2)) = 25:

[image: blue square, green spiral on graph]

The red line is the the angle on the spiral, and the blue lines are the high and base of the rectangle.

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, it is not research level, so, despite @JonathanLove's nice [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405788) and [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405787/how-can-i-find-the-area-of-a-rectangle-created-by-the-spiral-r-theta-at-a-certai#comment1040365_405788), it will probably be closed.  For future questions at this level, try our sister site [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parametric form for this spiral is given by $x=\theta\cos\theta$ and $y=\theta\sin\theta$. So the area of the rectangle is $\theta^2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac{\theta^2}{2}\sin(2\theta)$.

Comment: Also worth pointing out: the example you shared is not quite right. The correct value is $F(5\sqrt{2})=24.9996914\ldots$. The reason your picture looks the way it does is because $5\sqrt{2}$ is a very close approximation to $\frac{9\pi}{4}$.